# TypeScript Build in visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I just built my typescript in visual studio 2012,
on the first day, after I built the .ts file, the .js file is modified/adjusted according to the typescript .ts file that I made.

The strange thing is the next day, I open the project,
and I modify many code in the .ts file, after I compile it,
the .js file is not updated and not modified,
the worse is that I got the following error:

1. Permission Denied     EXEC File
2. The Command .... exited with code 1

in the Build output the error:

> ------ Rebuild All started: Project: HTML5Viewer, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>   1>  Couldn't write to file 'C:/DevProject/PADS 4.x/Release 2/Source/PADS HTML5/PADS HTML5 Viewer/HTML5Viewer/methods.js'
>   1>EXEC : tsc.js(21005, 21) Microsoft JScript runtime error : Permission denied
>   1>C:\DevProject\PADS 4.x\Release 2\Source\PADS HTML5\PADS HTML5 Viewer\HTML5Viewer\HTML5Viewer.csproj(73,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc" "C:\DevProject\PADS 4.x\Release 2\Source\PADS HTML5\PADS HTML5 Viewer\HTML5Viewer\Viewer.ts" "C:\DevProject\PADS 4.x\Release 2\Source\PADS HTML5\PADS HTML5 Viewer\HTML5Viewer\methods.ts" "C:\DevProject\PADS 4.x\Release 2\Source\PADS HTML5\PADS HTML5 Viewer\HTML5Viewer\app.ts"" exited with code 1.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

any solution to this?

I can just create a new project and move all my .ts files to the new ones
but that will be a pain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what source control system you are using, but if you have checked in the `.js` file and the build process isn't able to check it out to change it, this would cause an error such as the one you have.

You can either exclude the file entirely from source control or allow your build process to check out the file to edit it.

Comment: That was so simple, I follow your instruction that is I allow the check out on the .js file by modify it manually until there's a sign that the .js file is being modified, then I compile the .ts file, and the error is gone and the .js file is automatically modified